# Will DesktopCouch be stable in Natty?

Tags: ubuntu-one, 11.04, couchdb, desktopcouch

This is an important question for me. I have to decide to whether to use DesktopCouch or pure CouchDB.

Will DesktopCouch be stable in Natty?

Up to this point, I've had too many problems with DesktopCouch. DC does not start, DC does not sync, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Desktopcouch went through some rough patches during Natty, because we changed several things (both in desktopcouch itself, and in the libraries and services it depends on), but it will be stable by the time the beta comes out.

Comment: thx for your answer.